# No funciona Media Query

Tags: html, css

Estoy realizando un curso que incluye CSS responsive y al momento de realizar una tarea me solicita un Home con tarjetas, utilizando grid y adaptarlo con media query para tablet y celular. Lo que pasa es que al momento de implementar las media query en la pagina web no me las detecta.
La idea es que al llegar a un max-widht de 768 se acomoden en dos columnas de dos tarjetas y al llegar al max-widht de 480 se haga una sola columna con las cuatro tarjetas una debajo de la otra

```css
.card-container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffeedd;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
.card-container figure {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 50px 30px;
}
.card-container figure img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 10px 20px 40px 20px;
}
.card-container h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  text-align: center;
}
.card-container p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  text-align: justify;
}
@media screen and (max-widht: 768px) {
  .card-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 2fr);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-widht: 480px) {
  .card-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section class="card-container">
        <figure>
            <img src="/images/est-cont.jpg" alt="contabilidad">
            <h2>EL ESTUDIO</h2>
            <p>Estudio Contable SERVACO, brinda un asesoramiento integral a Unipersonales y PYMES en toda la etapa
                de su
                vida comercial.</p>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="/images/gest-aut.jpg" alt="gestoria">
            <h2>GESTORÍA AUTOMOTOR</h2>
            <p>Somos una prestigiosa gestoría automotor formada por un excelente equipo humano que abarca una amplia
                lista de servicios para brindarle.</p>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="/images/seg.jpg" alt="seguros">
            <h2>SEGUROS</h2>
            <p>Encontrarás una amplia variedad en seguros para personas y empresas: seguros de vida, pólizas de
                hogar, auto o moto y más</p>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="/images/novedades.jpg" alt="seguros">
            <h2>NOVEDADES</h2>
            <p>Te informamos cada día de las novedades impositivas a nivela nacional, provincial y municipal</p>
        </figure>
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Tenes mal escrita la palabra `width`, es `th` y pusiste `ht`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .card-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 2fr);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .card-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
}
```